# How to fix "Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: HTTPSConnectionPool" error?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

**I'm trying to install jupyterthemes package and getting this error.**

[image]

```
Collecting jupyterthemes
  Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(10054, 'An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host', None, 10054, None))': /packages/8a/08/9dee6dfd7f2aad6c30282d55c8f495b4dc1e4747b4e2bdbeb80572ddf312/jupyterthemes-0.20.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
  Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(10054, 'An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host', None, 10054, None))': /packages/8a/08/9dee6dfd7f2aad6c30282d55c8f495b4dc1e4747b4e2bdbeb80572ddf312/jupyterthemes-0.20.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
  Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(10054, 'An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host', None, 10054, None))': /packages/8a/08/9dee6dfd7f2aad6c30282d55c8f495b4dc1e4747b4e2bdbeb80572ddf312/jupyterthemes-0.20.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
  Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(10054, 'An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host', None, 10054, None))': /packages/8a/08/9dee6dfd7f2aad6c30282d55c8f495b4dc1e4747b4e2bdbeb80572ddf312/jupyterthemes-0.20.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
  Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(10054, 'An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host', None, 10054, None))': /packages/8a/08/9dee6dfd7f2aad6c30282d55c8f495b4dc1e4747b4e2bdbeb80572ddf312/jupyterthemes-0.20.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='files.pythonhosted.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /packages/8a/08/9dee6dfd7f2aad6c30282d55c8f495b4dc1e4747b4e2bdbeb80572ddf312/jupyterthemes-0.20.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (Caused by ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(10054, 'An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host', None, 10054, None)))
```

Comment: You seem to be running pip behind a proxy, if so run `pip --proxy "put proxy here" install jupyterthemes`

Answer (score 32):

It looks like you'd need to add trusted hosts.

Check [this](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/5309#issuecomment-383440367) GitHub thread out.

Something like:

```
sudo pip install --trusted-host=pypi.python.org --trusted-host=pypi.org --trusted-host=files.pythonhosted.org --upgrade --proxy=127.0.0.1:3128 jupyterthemes
```

Comment: I could not use this command to install because I got the error "Proxy URL had no scheme, should start with http:// or https://".  Instead to get it to work I used the command without the proxy argument: ``pip3 install --trusted-host=pypi.python.org --trusted-host=pypi.org --trusted-host=files.pythonhosted.org geopy``

Comment: Used all the --trusted-host=host.com wihtout the proxy part and solved it

Answer (score 7):

please check if date is set correctly. this error pops up usually when the time and date are different from that of the server.

Comment: I approve, this has failed like this to me just after midnight, when my local time is not sync with UTC because of timezone difference

Answer (score 3):

You may have a security software installed. **Zscaler** is usually the culprit in my case, but other security softwares may cause this error to be thrown.
`VnC's` answer is usually a quick fix. See [a permanent fix explained](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/topics/configuration/).

In summary you will need to create a configuration file `pip.ini` or `pip.conf` in Unix. You will need to include trusted hosts in the file like below:

```
# for system-wide configuration file
[global]
trusted-host = pypi.python.org
               pypi.org
               raw.githubusercontent.com
               files.pythonhosted.org
```

```
# per-user configuration file
[user]
trusted-host = pypi.python.org
               pypi.org
               raw.githubusercontent.com
               files.pythonhosted.org
```

```
# per-virtualenv configuration file
[site]
trusted-host = pypi.python.org
               pypi.org
               raw.githubusercontent.com
               files.pythonhosted.org
```

I'm on Windows OS. Refer to [the documentation](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/topics/configuration/) for your OS.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting proxy

```
set http_proxy=http://proxy.myproxy.com
set https_proxy=https://proxy.myproxy.com
python get-pip.py
```

Answer (score 1):

For me it happen due network firewall settings, try to connect to any other network and run the command. It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I think some packages need to be installed using administrator privileges
on mac try this:

> sudo pip install

on window:

you have to open **cmd** by running it as administrator.
I mean right click on cmd, choose

> run as administrator
> then
> pip install **pkg name**