# How can I install python packages in a virtual environment?

Tags: python, virtualenv, packageinstaller

I am trying to use virtualenv. I used this command to install the package:
`pip install virtualenv`
Then I create a folder using this command:
`python -m venv venv`
Now I want to use django package in this environment. What should should do? I got this error message:
Could not install packages due to an OSError: HTTPSConnectionPool ...

how to install any package in virtualenv

Comment: You use virtualenv but then you use *venv*, not virtualenv. Why? (Those are different packages!)

Comment: After activating the environment, installing packages should work as normal (simple pip install ...), can you add how you are activating your environment, as well as trying to install your dependencies?

Comment: Also, check if this applies to you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55688358/how-to-fix-could-not-install-packages-due-to-an-environmenterror-httpsconnecti

Comment: "due to an ``OSError: HTTPSConnectionPool ...``" the `...` are your actual problem here. The use of `venv` (you are not actually using `virtualenv`) is coincidental. In order for us to help you, we need to know what the `...` actually say.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

You can activate virtual environment:
on windows use venv\scripts\activate

Or
on Unix or Mac you can use source venv\bin\activate

Then install django

and if You are getting error message  OSError: HTTPSConnectionPool
Then it might be due to your internet connectivity problem.
Or
You can try to upgrade pip by pip install --upgrade pip

Comment: "*Or on Unix … source venv\bin\activate*" Doesn't work on Unix — wrong slant of slashes; must be different slashes.

Answer (score -1):

First activate the virtual environment

```
source venv/bin/activate
```

Then you can install packages using `pip install`